# Translating JS crypto.createHmac to Xojo Crypto.HMAC

Tags: javascript, xojo

I am trying to translate this block in Javascript:

```
const crypto = require('crypto'),
    shared_key = 'kw4qSnpSwXzgiv5yxYpZZmFEd9QAeiKTQ6OuyMja',
    signing_string = 'licenseSpring\ndate: Tue, 07 Jun 2011 20:51:35 GMT';

let signature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', shared_key).update(signing_string).digest('base64');

console.log(signature);
// UDysfR6MndUZReo07Y9r+vErn8vSxrnQ5ulit18iJ/Q=
```

Into Xojo:

```
Var shared_key as String = "kw4qSnpSwXzgiv5yxYpZZmFEd9QAeiKTQ6OuyMja"
Var signing_string as String =  "licenseSpring\ndate: Tue, 07 Jun 2011 20:51:35 GMT"

Var hash As String
hash = EncodeBase64(Crypto.HMAC(shared_key, signing_string, Crypto.HashAlgorithms.SHA256))
MessageBox(hash)
//Q4BAhsu1Xw3LsBZ+BCLShWQDbmJ2j/eFXzvF9T6n9tU=
```

I am getting two different hashed strings, but expect they should be the same. Are these algorithms equivalent?

Comment: It seems that you missed the final hmac.digest-call on Javascript/Crypto-side (see: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_hmac_digest_encoding) - at the moment you are "just" updating the calculation with update.

Comment: That's not right. The Xojo function Crypto.HMAC is calculating the digest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be this:

```
Var signing_string as String =  "licenseSpring" + EndOfLine.UNIX + "date: Tue, 07 Jun 2011 20:51:35 GMT"
```